# DynamoDBmapper vs DynamoDB Table instance

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

In order to use the most appropriate object, I try to figure out what are the differences between DynamoDBMapper and DynamoDB Table instance considering table construction, save, update, delete, query or scan operations.

Some methods:

```
    import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.Table;
    import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper;

    ...

    mapper.save(bean, saveExpression);
    mapper.delete(bean);

    table.putItem(bean)
    table.updateItem(bean)
    table.deleteItem(HASH_KEY_NAME, bean.getHashKeyVal());
```

Those methods give the same results. Is DynamoDBMapper just a layer to facilitate interactions with DynamoDB Tables, or are there any scalability, read or write optimisations ?

Thanks for informations.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you're asking about the difference between `com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper` and `com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBTableMapper`. Actually, the second [is a wrapper](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBTableMapper.java#L145) for the first that is able to work only with a single table. `DynamoDBMapper` can work with multiple tables [provided `DynamoDBMapperConfig` parameter for calls like `save()`](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapper.java#L510), while the `DynamoDBTableMapper` [captures single `DynamoDBMapperConfig` inside a field](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBTableMapper.java#L144) and uses it for the all the calls. `DynamoDBTableMapper` [forwards](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBTableMapper.java#L298) all the calls to the underlying `DynamoDBMapper`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I was talking about
com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.Table and
com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper, considering just one table. I was aware that mapper could performs operations on different tables, but is it the only advantage ?
I edit my post